# How to get this popup window style?

Tags: javascript, css

If you go to http://www.sharethis.com/ and click on the green shareThis widget next to the text 'Try it out', you'll see a window pop-up.

I've noticed everyone is beginning to use a pop-up window with this style.

What's this? Is it just a div or a new browser window? How to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out any one of these:

- [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/)
- [Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)
- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the popup-window is actually two divs, one which darkens the site, one for the window.
Also guessing: both could use the "opacity" and "z-index" css attributes.